# How to change type of input field on keypress - angularjs

Tags: css, angularjs

I want to change the type of input field from text to password.

On clicking the input field I am able to change the type from text to password but I also want to change the type from text to password on keypress of tab icon.

Can anyone help me.

My code changing type from text to password on onclick function is

```
<input type="text" name="password" class="form-control5 floating-input" ng-model="vm.password" required autocomplete="off" onclick="(this.type='password')" value="secure"/>
<span class="highlight"></span>
<span class="bar"></span>
<label for="password" class="field-name">Password</label>


label          {
  /*color:#999;*/ 
  font-size:16px;
  font-weight:normal;
  position:absolute;
  pointer-events:none;
  left:5px;
  top:10px;
  transition:0.2s ease all; 
}

.highlight {
  position:absolute;
  height:60%; 
  /*width:100px; */
  top:25%; 
  left:0;
  pointer-events:none;
  opacity:0.5;
}


.floating-label { 
  position:relative; 
  margin-bottom:20px; 
}

.floating-input , .floating-select {
  font-size:14px;
  padding:4px 4px;
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  height:30px;
  background-color: transparent;
  border:none;
  border-bottom:1px solid #ccc;
}

.floating-input:focus , .floating-select:focus {
     outline:none; 
}

    .floating-input:focus ~ label, .floating-input:not([value=""]):valid ~ label {
      top:-18px;
      font-size:14px;
      color:#333;
      font-weight: 600;
}
```

Comment: share what you have tried so far.. maybe a plunker/fiddle?

Comment: are you feasible with using javascript/Jquery.?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `onfocus` function similarly to `onclick`. Something like this

```
<input type="text" onfocus="this.type='password'" value="Password"/>
```

You can similarly change the type on focus out by using `onblur` event.

```
<input type="text" onblur="this.type='text'" value="Password"/>
```

Comment: @sudarsan: i hope this is something that you require

Comment: I used both onfocus and onblur in same input field. Now it is working. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I hope is the solution you are seeking, you can try it.

```js
var app = angular.module('cft', []);
app.controller('changeproperty', function($scope) {
  $scope.vm = {};
  $scope.fieldType = 'text';
  $scope.changeField = function(){
    $scope.fieldType = 'password';
  };
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="cft">
  <div ng-controller="changeproperty">
    <input type="{{fieldType}}" name="password" class="form-control5 floating-input" ng-blur="changeField()" ng-model="vm.password" required autocomplete="off" value="secure"/>
    <span class="highlight"></span>
    <span class="bar"></span>
    <label for="password" class="field-name">{{fieldType}}</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to bind the `input`'s attribute `type` with a model of the controller as below:

```
<input type="{{inputType}}" />
```

Also attach the `ng-focus` and `ng-blur` attributes to it.

```
<input ng-focus="modifyType('password')" ng-blur="modifyType('text')" />
```

The method definition in controller:

```
 $scope.modifyType = function(type) {
    $scope.inputType = type;
 }
```

[**Demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/t28c8c4k/)

Answer (score 0):

How I solved this was adding a boolean variable and a function that toggles this variable in the controller. For example:

```
$scope.showPassword = false;
$scope.togglePassword = function() {
    $scope.showPassword = !$scope.showPassword
```

}

and in the html I added this implementation, this is using ternary operator:

```
<input type='{{(showPassword)? text : password }}' />
<i class='{{(showPassword)? icon-eye-open : icon-eye-close }}' ng-click='togglePassword()' ><i/>
```